# Font is being ignored when app is built?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts, sprite-kit

So I have just finished making a game (with help from @Fluidity) and when I build it the fonts requested are all ignored. I have selected fonts to be used in main.storyboard but when it gets to the game the default is used. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you may need to delete the fonts and then add them again (move to trash). IDK honestly I tried 4x :{ the fonts aren't working for me now either

Comment: @Fluidity I fixed it by clicking on the font where you can select Gamescene.swift etc and then checking the box on the right that says "Target Membership"

Comment: wow, my bad. I saw that but was like "wtf of course fonts would be project wide"

Comment: that was my bad in importing i was too lazy to click that button. lessons learned

Comment: @Fluidity don't worry it's sorted now :)

Comment: grats on fixing it. was a derp on my end, and a W00T on yours. keep up the good problem solving skillz

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the file in your project and specify this font in your `Info.plist`

For example, add the following in your `Info.plist`

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>Fluidity.otf</string>
</array>
```

I'm assuming the filename is `Fluidity.otf`

Comment: This is true when loading from anywhere inside code,  but inside IB, this should have been fixed so that you do not need to change the Info.plist, so I would also check to make sure that it got included as a resource, because XCode does forget to add this from time to time.

Comment: I tried adding the file and it still didn't load, despite it being in the main project directory and showing in xcode

Comment: @Fluidity did you modify `Info.plist`?

Comment: yes, it turned out to be that it wasn't added as a target

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by Checking the box in Target Membership relevant to the necessary application.

Target membership is located on the right after clicking your custom font under your application files.